# Invoking WCF service method through a browser

Tags: wcf, web-services

I've a WCF service which uses basic http binding.
How do I invoke its operations/methods through a browser?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend setting up multiple endpoints for the Service.  Add an endpoint using webHttpBinding to get an XML version of the service.  If this is done correctly the response you will get from the service is identical to the basicHttpBinding endpoint, but without the SOAP overhead.

Other than that, you can't call a SOAP web service directly from the browser because it requires a form post.  You could use a tool to test it using SOAP though, I recommend [Soap UI](http://www.soapui.org/).  Its written in Java but I try not to hold that against it.  :)

Answer (score 36):

You would need to add WebGetAttribute to your method like following sample

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/placesList/{userId}",
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
List<Places> GetAllPlacesForUser(String userId)
{
  string xml = "";
  // build xml here
  return xml;
}
```

Now in the browser, you could invoke the method like this

> http://localhost:8085/GeoPlacesDataService/placesList/10
>   where 10 is the userId parameter.

Note: *In order to add WebGetAttribute you have to reference System.ServiceModel.Web namespace which is found in a separate assembly*

Answer (score 6):

After adding the above code, the endpoint property has to be modified in **web.config**, `binding="webHttpBinding"` and `behaviorConfiguration="webHttp"`.

Comment: Would you mind to specify the tags that contain these properties, please?
Or it would be very kind of you if you provide us with your web.config file.