# WCF Configuration File for Browser Interaction?

Tags: wcf, data-binding, browser

I have a simple WCF 4.0 service with some simple methods and a property with a getter that returns List. The service works fine when connected to programatically. The getter is decorated as are the other methods on the Interface that define the service contract.

My next move is to make the service accessible via the IE web browser so server/deployment admins can do a "smoketest" after service installation.

This works currently:

```
http://localhost/myservice.svc?wsdl
```

But I need to take things further and get this to work:

```
http://localhost/myservice.svc/SmokeTest
```

and have results show in the browser, SmokeTest is the property with a getter that does stuff and returns the List I want to show in the browser.

So far I can't figure out what my config should look like. All help appreciated.

This is all I have in the web.config for the service. The endpoint is myservice.svc:

```
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" /> 
    <services>
        <service name="myservice.worker"  >
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="myservice.IServicio" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

related question, an explanation of what can and can't be done:

[Invoking WCF services through a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802518/invoking-wcf-service-method-through-a-browser)

Comment: Making a WCF service REST compliant gives some for-free browser viewint/debugging. Now I have a problem getting it to run under IIS5.1. Ugh. But thanks!