# How to call WCF service OperationContract from browser?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf, dll, iis-7

I created a `WCF 4` web services and hosted it on my `IIS 7`, I gave the following `Service URL:` at publish web section in `WCF` project:

`http://localhost:8084/service1.svc`.

Then i bind my published `web site` on port:`4567` and Type: `http` in `IIS`.

```
To checked it i clicked on `web site` at `IIS` and click on the browse. 
It open a following page at my browser:
```

[image]

It means that the web service is successfully hosted on `IIS`. Now i want to call my instances method and return the output at browser. Let me paste you the sample code of `Iservice.cs` and `service.svc.cs`

```
#Iservice.cs:
namespace some.decryption
{
[ServiceContract]
public interface Iservice
{
  [OperationContract, WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/getdata", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string getdata();
}}
```

Whereas my `service.svc.cs`:

```
public bool getdata()
    {
        return somenamespace.getfetcheddll();
    }
```

and `serviceDll.cs`:

```
  namespace somenamespace{
  internal static class UnsafeNativeMethods
   {
   _dllLocation = "some.dll";
   [DllImport(_dllLocation, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
   public static extern bool OnDecryption();
   }

  public static string getfetcheddll()
   {
       return UnsafeNativeMethods.OnDecryption();
   }}
```

how should i call `getdata()` method from browsers?

I have put the `some.dll` in the same project folder. Where should i do it?

### Edit:

I have forgot to paste my `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

To do this i followed this blog : [walkthrough on creating](http://debugmode.net/2010/09/07/walkthrough-on-creating-wcf-4-0-service-and-hosting-in-iis-7-5/)

Comment: Let me paste you my `web.config`

Comment: @marc_s pasted at code section

Comment: That unfortunately still doesn't show what **binding** is being used.... seems you're using the WCF 4 default endpoints... are you adding service endpoints in code, on the server side? If so: please show that code... By default - HTTP is translated into `wsHttpBinding` which is a **SOAP** service --> cannot be called from a browser just like that. The `?wsdl` suffix on the help page also seems to point in that direction

Comment: Try using the [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) - can you connect to your service at the URL shown on the help page with that tool? Do you see your service?

Comment: @marc_s I just followed a blog pasted at the code section. Please have a brief review to it. This is my first `WCF` service project

Comment: that's a **SOAP** service for sure - cannot call that with a browser only - see my answer for two tools to test your WCF Service.

Comment: I hope here is the an answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802518/invoking-wcf-service-method-through-a-browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default - `HTTP` is translated into `wsHttpBinding` which is a **SOAP** service, so you **cannot** just call that from a browser. The `?wsdl` suffix on the help page also seems to point in that direction.

For testing SOAP services, you need a SOAP-capable tool like the Microsoft [WCF Test Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364.aspx) or [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org).

Try using the WCF Test Client - can you connect to your service at the URL shown on the help page with that tool? Do you see your service?

Comment: Is the `WCF Test Client` is kind of exe ? I have never use it

Comment: @AmitPal: yes - it's a separate, stand-alone WCF test tool. Download it and play around with it - it's free and quite useful. Or use SoapUI - also free and VERY useful

Comment: What about the dll section ? where should i placed it

Comment: @AmitPal: that's part of the **service** - you need to make sure your service is functional and up and running; the WCF Test client is a **client** application to test the service - the client **must not** depend on a DLL that the service uses!

Comment: I tested it with `WCF test client` and it works fine with the methods which are not using dll, but with them it shows an error