# Creating web interface for WCF service

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, web-services, wcf

I have two projects right now - a WCF service that pulls from a database, and an ASP.NET project with AngularJS that acts as the interface. My question - is there a way to combine the two into a single project? What I would like to happen: when running the WCF service, my interface should appear in the browser instead of the traditional XML page. I know it's possible to stick the service's dll into the interface's file structure, but I want the interface to be within the service, not the other way around. Is this possible? Does anyone know how this might be done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can combine WCF and ASP.NET projects into a single project. Just ensure to add all your references from WCF project to ASP.NET project and also any web.config files settings.

Can you provide more information on the 2nd part of the question, " my interface should appear in the browser instead of the traditional XML page"?

Comment: Usually when running a WCF service, if you go to the .svc URL, you get a page something like this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/261791. I want to run my WCF service and see my interface instead. So I need to somehow get the interface files into the WCF project, not the other way around.

Comment: To see individual methods you can use  WCF Test Client o rSoapUI. Some linke here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159771/how-to-call-wcf-service-operationcontract-from-browser

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to strongly suggest keeping two projects. It's generally considered good architecture to build software in logical layers. In your case, you have a Business/Data-Access layer and a Presentation layer. Very common. Merging them would be a mistake! You would certainly wind up with crossed concerns over time; while if you keep them separate, you will have testable layers.

Additionally, it's often a good idea to separate your interfaces into yet another project, such that all others depend on it as the infrastructure or skeleton of the whole solution.

Layered architecture reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658109.aspx

Comment: I absolutely agree with that. But is it possible to somehow just have another sub-URL perhaps when running the service that goes to my interface?

Comment: I suspect what you want lies here, Hosting WCF and ASP.NET side-by-side: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx

Comment: Alternatively if all you want to do is provide access to the .SVC or WSDL off an arbitrary URL, you can simply copy the WCF interface and .SVC into a directory. I just did copied from WCF project into Web, and got the Service instructions at http://localhost:15644/Test/Service1.svc

Comment: Interesting... I added the Asp compatibility mode stuff as you suggested, and now when I run the project the WCF Test Client opens. Would there be a way then to open my client application instead?

Comment: Not sure. Did the project properties Web -> Start Action change to be the Test Client?

Comment: No, it is still set to "Current Page"