# WCF Webservices in visual studio

Tags: android, asp.net, wcf, web-services, wcf-rest

i am new and need some help.
i have created an wcf service application in visual studio and write an simple method of login which receive an parameter userid & password then return an object of logged user object which have two fields name and organization.

**LoggedUser Class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace crmpp_android_service
{
    public class LoggedUser
    {
        public string name;
        public string organization;
        [DataMember]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
        [DataMember]
        public string Organization
        {
            get { return organization; }
            set { organization = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

**OperationContract:**

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
             RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "login/?userid={userid} & pass={pass}"
        )]
        [Description("User Login return username & Organization currently affiliated")]
        LoggedUser login(string userid, string pass);
```

**Method Implementation in Service1.svc:**

```
  public LoggedUser login(string userid , string pass)
        {
            LoggedUser log_usr = new LoggedUser();
            log_usr.name = "Ahsan Mehdi";
            log_usr.organization = "JDC";
            return log_usr;
        }
```

but when i run application by pressing ctrl+F5 it open an wcf test Client like this and return data.
[image]

I am unable to get response from android app or simply from browser when i write URL for service it shows me page like that.

```
http://localhost:57127/Service1.svc
```

[image]

and when complete url like this

```
http://localhost:57127/Service1.svc/login/?userid=abc123&pass123
```

it returns nothing any guidelike or help please as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understand you want to access this WCF url which is hosted on your localhost machine not on IIS. For accessing your localhost webservice use this instead of localhost

```
http://10.0.2.2:Port/Service1.svc/login/?userid=abc123&pass123
```

And on IIS use the system IP which is assigned to you.

```
http://192.168.0.123:Port/Service1.svc/login/?userid=abc123&pass123
```

I hope this will clear your issue regarding connecting to android project.

Answer (score 0):

Get WCFstorm.  When you run it, add a new service, and copy the url of the service (in your screenshot, it's showing as:

```
localhost:57127/Service.svc
```

That will allow you to test the service.

This is what I use at work for testing WCF services.

Another tool I use is Fiddler.

Comment: thanks for reply but actually i want to access these methods of services from android application. where i will have to use service method path as 
**http://localhost:57127/Service1.svc/login/?userid=abc123&pass123**
so this should return some data in json formate but it is not.

Comment: What endpoints do you have set up?  Are you able to get a wsdl?

Comment: i am getting an xml page from this url 
**http://localhost:57127/Service1.svc?singleWsdl**

and this url **svcutil.exe http://localhost:57127/Service1.svc?wsdl** does not work

Comment: In your screenshot, the url of the wsdl you're looking for should be localhost:57127/Service1.svc?wsdl, or did you move it?  Also, I don't know of any way to invoke a service through a browser url. You will need to set up endpoints and call those.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802518/invoking-wcf-service-method-through-a-browser may help explain it a little better.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. i have not moved that service and i am able to test this service through wcf test client correctly.
let me check endpoints